# jqGrid grouping feature disappear when run addRowData

Tags: jqgrid

The jqGrid's website has following code example about how to use grouping feature, it works very well.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var mydata = [
                {id:"1",invdate:"2010-05-24",name:"test",note:"note",tax:"10.00",total:"2111.00"} ,
                {id:"2",invdate:"2010-05-25",name:"test2",note:"note2",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
    ....
            ];
          $("#list48").jqGrid({
            data: mydata,
            datatype: "local",
            height: 'auto',
            rowNum: 30,
            rowList: [10,20,30],
                colNames:['Inv No','Date', 'Client', 'Amount','Tax','Total','Notes'],
                colModel:[
                    {name:'id',index:'id', width:60, sorttype:"int"},
                    {name:'invdate',index:'invdate', width:90, sorttype:"date", formatter:"date"},
                    {name:'name',index:'name', width:100, editable:true},
                    {name:'amount',index:'amount', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float", formatter:"number", editable:true},
                    {name:'tax',index:'tax', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float", editable:true},      
                    {name:'total',index:'total', width:80,align:"right",sorttype:"float"},      
                    {name:'note',index:'note', width:150, sortable:false}       
                ],
                pager: "#plist48",
                viewrecords: true,
                sortname: 'name',
                grouping:true,
                groupingView : {
                    groupField : ['name'],
                    groupDataSorted:false, 
                    groupColumnShow:[true]
                },
                caption: "Grouping Array Data"
          });
```

But if I remove:

```
data: mydata,
```

And compose the grid by using addRowData:

```
$('#list48').addRowData("id", mydata);
```

The grouping disappeared, anybody experience similar issue ? Could you please help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try calling sortGrid after addRowData. That worked for me. Syntax for sortGrid is at http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods

```
var sortByColumnKey = 'StartDate';
$('#grid').jqGrid('sortGrid', sortByColumnKey, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same issue. Just triggering 'reloadGrid' solved it for me. 
$('#grid').trigger('reloadGrid');

Answer (score 0):

Grouping is not taken after adding rows on `$('#list48').addRowData("id", mydata);`

You should re-group with new data added in grid. Try this after adding rows to grid.

```
$('#list48').jqGrid('groupingGroupBy', 'name', {
                groupDataSorted:false, 
                groupColumnShow:[true]
});
```